# Extracting Export Functions From DLL

Tags: dll, portable-executable, dllexport

I am trying to write a function that pulls the names of the export functions from dll files. The interpreter I am using does not have access to winAPI and am restricted to some very basic binary-parsing functions to accomplish this.

So far I have been able to locate the basic components of PE header, PE optional header, and COFF header. By traversing these structures I am able to locate the IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT within the data_directory of the optional header (QWORD).

Where I am stuck is locating the IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY from the IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT? My understanding is that the IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT contains two relevant pieces of information Name Offset/Integer Id (first DWORD) and Data Entry Offset (second DWORD).

I've tried to follow the data entry offset, but it doesn't seem to be accurate, since (if it were absolute) it would be located before the PE header...which can't be right.

This leads me to think that it is a relative offset, but I have no idea what it would be relative to.

So in summary, is there a relationship between IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT to IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY, and if so how do you go from the first to the absolute offset of the second?

Comment: `IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY` containing RVA - offset from mapped image base. in what here problem ?

Comment: @RbMm that may be the piece I'm missing is that how you derive the absolute offset given an RVA?

Comment: @JaminBecker - how you map image in memory ? it mapped as image or "line" loaded as file. if mapped as image - direct use rva. if you need convert rva to file offset - you need walk by `IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER` array and look to which section this rva belong. after this `(rva - VirtualAddress) + PointerToRawData`

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly:

1. I'd be getting the RVA from the second DWORD of an DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_RESOURCE]

2. Walk the IMAGE_SECTION_HEADERs directly after the PE Optional Header.

3. Locate the one where DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_RESOURCE].RVA == IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER[i].VirtualAddress
4. Get the VirtualAddress and PointerToRawData from that particular IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER
5. (DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_RESOURCE].RVA - IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER[i].VirtualAddress) + IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER[i].PointerToRawData

Comment: 1.) - how is image mapped in memory ? this is key point. if you want convert rva to file offset - `DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_RESOURCE].RVA == IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER[i].VirtualAddress` this is of course wrong. rva in section if `rva - VirtualAddress < VirtualSize`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159265/discussion-between-jamin-becker-and-rbmm).